# webpack ProvidePlugin doesn't work for breeze

Tags: webpack, breeze, webpack-4, webpack-provide-plugin

I am trying to use breeze with a TypeScript web application that uses webpack (4.20.2).
These entries are in my npm package.json file:

```
"dependencies": {
    "bootstrap": "3.3.6",
    "breeze-client": "1.7.1",
    "es6-promise-promise": "1.0.0",
    "jquery": "2.2.1"
  }
```

I have a vendor webpack config that has the following:

```
  entry: {
            vendor: [
                'bootstrap',
                'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css',
                'breeze-client',
                'es6-promise-promise',
                'jquery'
            ]
        },
   plugins: [
            new webpack.ProvidePlugin({ 
                  $: 'jquery', 
                  jQuery: 'jquery', 
                  Promise: 'es6-promise-promise', 
                  Q: "q" 
            })
        ]
```

I was getting

> Error: Q is undefined. Are you missing Q.js? See
>   https://github.com/kriskowal/q

So I added a polyfill to my code to use ES6 Promises for Q, and do this in my startup code:

```
import { config } from 'breeze-client'
import { Q } from './lib/my-q-implementation';
config.setQ(Q)
```

Now I get this:

> Unable to locate jQuery

I'm pretty sure boostrap looks for a global jQuery, so I think the problem is breeze.

Why is breeze not seeing the global jQuery? How do I fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Very hacky but I got it working using the imports-loader.

```
module: {
 rules: [
    { 
     test: require.resolve('breeze-client/breeze.debug'), 
     use: 'imports-loader?this=>window,window.jQuery=jquery,window.ko=knockout,global=>{window: this}' 
    },
   ]
}
```

Which puts this at the top of the breeze script.

```
var window = (window || {});
window.jQuery = __webpack_require__(/*! jquery */ "./node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js");
var window = (window || {});
window.ko = __webpack_require__(/*! knockout */ "./node_modules/knockout/build/output/knockout-latest.debug.js");
var global = {window: this};
```

I don't like it because it puts jquery and ko in the global scope.

I tried this, among other things, (for jquery) and it did not work:

```
plugins: [
            new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
                $: "jquery",
                jQuery: "jquery",
                "window.jQuery": "jquery",
                "global.window.jQuery": "jquery"
            }),
```

AND with this in place, I still have to do this in another script that references "$":

```
import * as $ from 'jquery';
```

Tried this in my startup script also with no luck:

```
import jQuery as $ from 'jquery';
window.jQuery = window.$ = jQuery;
```

Hope this helps someone and hope someone can chime in with a better solution.